# Send query parameter via pagination submit buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I have a page helper that creates the list of submit buttons with page numbers for particular form:

```
public static IHtmlContent PageButtons(this IHtmlHelper html, PagingInfo pagingInfo)
        {
            var listOfButtons = new TagBuilder("li");
            listOfButtons.AddCssClass("markers_list_list");

            for (int i = 1; i <= pagingInfo.TotalPages; i++)
            {
                TagBuilder button = new ("button");

                button.MergeAttribute("type", "submit");
                button.MergeAttribute("form", "mainForm");
                button.InnerHtml.AppendHtmlLine(i.ToString());

                if ((i < (pagingInfo.CurrentPage - 5) || i > (pagingInfo.CurrentPage + 5)) && (i > 1 & i < pagingInfo.TotalPages))
                    button.AddCssClass("d-none");

                if (i == pagingInfo.CurrentPage)
                {
                    button.AddCssClass("selected");
                    button.AddCssClass("btn-primary");
                }

                button.AddCssClass("btn btn-default");

                listOfButtons.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(button);

            }

            return listOfButtons;
        }
```

And I use it like this in my view:

```
 <div class="entities_list_page_links">
            @Html.PageButtons(Model.PagingInfo))
        </div>
```

Now when some button is clicked, I want that the number associated with that button is passed as query parameter. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ajax to achieve it. Because your `<button/>` is generated in your custom html helper, I can't add onclick method on it directly, So I use **JS** to add 'click()' method dynamically.

```
<div class="entities_list_page_links">
            @Html.PageButtons(Model)
    </div>


@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $('.entities_list_page_links').find('button').click(function(){
               var CurrentPage = $(this).text(); 

              //send request

               $.get("/Home/Privacy?CurrentPage="+CurrentPage);
               
           })
        })
    </script>
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Edited=========================

**ViewModel**

```
public class PagingInfoViewModel
{
    public PagingInfo pagingInfo { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
}
```

Page

```
@model PagingInfoViewModel


<form asp-action="Demo" method="get" id="mainForm">

    @* add the hidden input to send the page number  *@
    <input name="CurrentPage" type="hidden" id="current" value=""/>

    <div class="entities_list_page_links">
        @Html.PageButtons(Model.pagingInfo)
    </div>
    
</form>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $('.entities_list_page_links').find('button').click(function(){
               var CurrentPage = $(this).text(); 
               
               //pass the page number from button to hidden input
               $('#current').attr("value",CurrentPage); 
           })
        })
    </script>
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, however, I already can send the request with what I have in my code. the only piece of data that I can't send is the page number. What would be ideal for me is if somehow inside my helper I can set ' asp-for' with the value of the button number

Comment: Hi @Ivan, I get your point. Because your `button` is generated in your custom html helper class, So you can't add `asp-for=` in it. But , Why we must need button to pass the page number? I create a hidden type, Then every time page reload, I use js to pass the value of page number from the button to the hidden input, It will send the page number, I have updated my answer, you can refer to it.

Comment: excellent, this is exactly what I wanted!